# I want to track file and filesystem changes to be aware of possible security breaches. Can I use Subversion for this task?

Tags: security, svn, filesystemwatcher

I am new to Subversion and cannot find the answer as to how it behaves if the files of the repository are changed from outside Subversion e.g. someone simply doing a copy into the repository, rather than svn copy. In this case, if I browse the repository, will Subversion tell me, that there are new files or directories, that are unversioned? What happens if I delete a file? I use RapidSVN, and I know, that when I want to commit files, it works like this, on the working copy side, but I don't know how the repository behaves on the server side.

I will tell you what do I want to achieve. Our website has been cracked. My boss wants me to write a script, that would monitor the filesystem and create reports on file and filesystem changes (filesize, filename, last modified, permissions). Subversion essentially does this, and I am wondering, if I could actually use Subversion for this task, call it's commands and process the output.

Comment: "Our website has been cracked" - so are you saying your source code is on the server?  A better course of action would be to secure your web site!!

Comment: Hey Mitch! Yes, ofcourse, we have already made steps toward that, but we don't know how and where did they get in. That is why my boss wants to monitor websites file tree, so we can make reports and automate warnings if something is going on. I appreciate your advice, but other than that, what do you think? Can I use svn for the purpose of monitoring the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is **not** a file system audit tool - you should:

1. Secure your server
2. Back your server up
3. For Version control consider using a distributed VCS such as git or mecurial.

I would strongly suggest asking about security on one of the other SO Sites such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I guess it was my fault that my question was misunderstandable - I know, what svn is and is not. Nevertheless, your answer contained within the phrase I was looking for: 'file system audit'. Thanks. :)